# Why is there a limit to number of validators?

Tags: proof-of-stake, casper

In Casper and consensus-by-bet, validators make bets, and converge on a block at each block height, etc. In the Casper PoCs so far, the number of validators at any given block has been limited to 250, or 4000 (in the mauve paper). What are the technical reasons there is a limit?

Comment: we don't understand you mean by that. Your question is very vague. Please clarify

Comment: In Casper and consensus-by-bet, validators make bets, and converge on a block at each block height, no? In PoCs so far, the number of validators at any given block, has been limited to 250, or 4000 (in the mauve paper)

What are the reasons there a limit? Game theory, technical, and so on.